# Can sufficiently large topologies only be generated by basis?

Tags: general-topology, intuition

Okay, so this is a very speculative idea but it is an impression I got from reading Munkres. The thing is that every topology that I have seen defined on an infinite set where there is at least one open neighborhood for every member (*) in the set seems to be generated by a basis. For example on $\mathbb{R}$,

1. The lower limit topology
2. Standard topology
3. K topology

I think maybe that "open neighborhood covering each member" thing is too strong. The point I want to say is, **if the topology is too large then it can only be written down as "generated by a basis"**. These subsets could be characterized by having certain forms eg: $\left[ a,b \right)$ ,  $(a,b)$ etc.

Is my observation general? And, if so, is there a formalization for the ideas I described?

Thanks for your guidance.

---

*: Excluding whole set $X$ as it is neighborhood of a point

Also I am excluding discrete topology for the above discussion

Comment: The [discrete topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_space) can be large. If you assume the [power set axiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_power_set) valid, I guess you would consider this as a topology in which we "give" all its elements.

Comment: Any topology is generated by a basis comprising the open sets of the topology. Many topologies, e.g., the standard topology on Euclidean $n$-space have noce bases, but that's just the mathematical universe being kind to us: there are a vast number of possible topologies on any set of order 3 or more.

Comment: Basis is always there I think

Comment: In a way, yes. Even the usual topology on $\Bbb R$ has $2^{\aleph_0}$ open sets so we cannot give a simple "formula" for all of them. An advanced example: The Wallmann extension $w\Bbb N$ of the discrete topology on $\Bbb N$ ( equivalently, the maximal [Cech-Stone] compactification of $\Bbb N).$ The points of $w\Bbb N$ are ultra-filters on $\Bbb N.$  A base (basis) for $w\Bbb N$ is $\{U^*:U\subseteq \Bbb N\}$ where $U^*$ is the set of every ultra-filter $F$ on $\Bbb N$ such that $U\in F.$

Comment: Hmm I understand that it is trivially so, but my question is sometimes that you NEED to use a basis to define? @RobArthan

Comment: Every topology has a basis. Existence of minimal base is all that matter. The cardinality of the minimal base is called weight of the topology. "If the weight is big in sense of cardinality or basic open sets haven't any special form then the introduction of basis is useless ".

Comment: Could you explain the thing in quotation again? @SouravGhosh

Comment: $|w(\tau) |\le |\mathcal{P}(X) |$ but sometimes it's very (very) difficult to find minimal base . For an example a non discrete $T_1$ space has no minimal base. In particular choose co-finite topology on an infinite set. Then given any basis, we can find another one contained in that given basis. If the topological space is second countable then we can select a countable basic open set.

Comment: I don't understand your comment about needing to use a basis. Defining a topology by giving a basis is often very convenient for reasoning about the topology, but in very many cases the "right" definition of the topology is via a more abstract structural property: e.g., the product topology is the least topology that makes all the projection functions continuous.

Comment: Besides excluding the discrete topology, you'll have to exclude cofinite topologies, and Zariski topologies, and who knows what else you'll have to exclude. But the other thing you'll have to do is to explain what the boldfaced sentence means: Is there some mathematical meaning to the statement **if the topology is too large then it can only be written down as "generated by a basis"**?

Comment: I think so if you do the structural property, when dealing with infinite sets, the topology in which the continuity for individual projection function is established should be generated by basis @RobArthan

Comment: My point is that the nicest way to make the definition is to take the structural property as the definition and then prove a theorem to say that this is equivalent to the definition in terms of a basis. I.e., there is no **need** to make the definition in terms of a basis and it gives better insight not to do so.

Comment: I don't think I understand you very well. Could you explain more/Rephrase please?/ @RobArthan

Comment: The insightful definition of the product topology is to say it is the weakest topology that makes all the projections continuous. This definition makes no use of the concept of a basis, but does tell us exactly the properties we want the product topology to have. The definition in terms of a basis does not give any insight into the motivation for the product topology.

Comment: Okay, but I think that is like a one off thing, other than the product topology are there other example of topology defined by general structural property of sets? @RobArthan

Comment: Yes there are loads of such examples. @LeeMosher has given some interesting ones in the comments above. The usual situation when you introduce a new topology is that you want to identify an interesting set of functions that are going to be continue and then the natural way to make the definition is in terms of that interesting set of functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cofinite topology on $\Bbb N$ can be defined by $\tau = \{S : |\Bbb N \setminus S| < |\Bbb N|\}$ (where $|A|$ is the cardinality of the set $A$). No basis used (excepting that $\tau$ is a basis for itself).

There are many other examples of defining topologies by other means than bases. They are less widely used because defining topologies by bases is usually more convenient.

Comment: I disagree with your claim that defining topologies without using bases is rare: see the comments on the question.

Comment: @RobArthan - true - I was not cautious enough with my wording, and severely overstated the point. I'll reword it.

Comment: Thank you, Paul!